# Можно ли сократить/оптимизировать код при выводе функции print()?

Tags: python, оптимизация, print

Дано задание: написать программу, которая генерирует сто случайных вещественных чисел и заполняет ими список.
Выводит получившийся список на экран по десять элементов в ряд. Далее сортирует список с помощью
метода sort() и снова выводит его на экран по десять элементов в строке. Для вывода списка напишите
отдельную функцию, в качестве аргумента она должна принимать список.
а если чисел будет 100++++++, можно ли как-то отформатировать вывод?

```
def PrintList(c):
    print(c[0:10], c[10:20], c[20:30], c[30:40], c[40:50], c[50:60],
      c[60:70], c[70:80], c[80:90], c[90:100], sep='\n')
def PrintSortList(c):
    c.sort()
    print(c[0:10], c[10:20], c[20:30], c[30:40], c[40:50], c[50:60],
      c[60:70], c[70:80], c[80:90], c[90:100], sep='\n')

import random
c = []
i = 0
while i < 100:
    c.append(round(random.random(), 2))
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В задании было сказано

> Для вывода списка напишите отдельную функцию, в качестве аргумента она
> должна принимать список.

Функция `dump` печатает правильно отформатированный список любой длины:

```
import random


def dump(lst, size=10):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), size):
        print(*lst[i:i + size])


data = [round(random.random(), 2) for _ in range(105)]
dump(data)
data.sort()
dump(data)
```

Comment: в этой строке:  data = [round(random.random(), 2) for _ in range(105)], символ "_" как обрабатывается?

Comment: Он никак не используется. Формально `_` - правильное имя переменной. В Питоне никто никогда не использует это имя для настоящих переменных. Я его использовал чтобы показать что значение счётчика мне безразлично, интересны только 105 повторений цикла.

Answer (score 3):

вот так что ли нужно?

```
import random

# сгенерируем 105 случайных чисел (чтобы проверить и не кратные 10 случаи)
data = [random.random() for _ in range(105)]

# формируем список строк в каждой из которых по 10 чисел
res = [' '.join(map(str, data[i:i+10])) for i in range(0, len(data), 10)]

# выводим список в столбик
print(*res, sep='\n')

# сортируем сгенерированный список
data.sort()

# формируем список строк в каждой из которых по 10 чисел
res = [' '.join(map(str, data[i:i+10])) for i in range(0, len(data), 10)]

# выводим список в столбик
print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Comment: за "map" не знал, где-то есть собранная в кучу информация про эти дополнительные функции?

Comment: э... честно говоря без понятия :) просто когда задаешь себе вопрос "а можно ли проще сделать", то потихоньку всякие такие вещи и начинаешь использовать

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

вариант решения с использованием генератора:

```
from random import choices

c = choices(range(10),k=105)  # список случайных чисел      

def it(l):
    while l:
        yield l[:10]  # генератор выдает по порядку по 10 элементов
        l = l[10:]
        
def print_list(n):
    for i in it(n): print(*i)  # в цикле обращаемся к генератору и выводим на печать
        
print_list(c)
print_list(sorted(c))

'''
4 5 5 8 1 1 1 6 3 4
3 9 4 5 9 2 1 2 9 6
2 7 9 5 4 6 1 8 6 5
1 3 6 7 1 0 9 5 7 2
1 7 1 2 4 3 7 1 8 6
5 4 8 0 3 7 5 1 0 4
8 8 6 1 4 3 2 9 8 4
3 9 3 7 9 9 1 3 8 4
6 3 6 5 9 5 3 3 0 7
0 6 8 2 7 4 1 1 7 3
1 9 7 6 9

0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9
```